# NullReferenceException on XtraGrid Gridview rowclick event (Filter row)

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, devexpress

```
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
{              
   WriteUsersInformation((User)grdPersonel.MainView.GetRow(e.RowHandle));                        
}
```

I use a filter area on the gridview so if the user click the filter area "NullReferenceException was unhandled" error show up. how I could distinguish the selecting row a datarow or the filter so I wanna put a control. I am really new for coding, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, your English isn't helping much, I can't understand what do you need. Where are you from? Maybe I can understand your question in a language you master.

Comment: I only wanna find how I seperate the clicking row, it is row or the filter in datagrid. I am using devexpress datagridview and ıts filter option, and c#. I am turkish.

Comment: So essentially u have different rows .. some rows or 1 row is a filter and the other ones data. Now when u select a filter row u get the exception. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.RowHandle < 0)
{
    //Invalid row
}  
else
{
    WriteUsersInformation((User)grdPersonel.MainView.GetRow(e.RowHandle));   
}
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work I still having the same error and e.rowHandle is int so e.RowHandle != 0 I try. I have "is never equal to 'null' of type 'int" warning.

Comment: if e.rowhandle returns an int then try e.RowHandle < 0

Answer (score 0):

I think by filter area you mean the auto filter row, if so, you can check if the selected row handle is equal to the auto filter row handle

```
if (e.RowHandle != DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle)
{
// your code
}
```

But I realy suggest you write a safer code, simply by checking if your user object is not null.

```
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
{
    var user = gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as User;
    if (user == null)
        return;

    WriteUsersInformation(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
    {

        object oUsr = grdPersonel.MainView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        if (oUsr is User)
            WriteUserInformation((User)oUsr);

       }
```

when last user click on the auto filter row my current object getting null, I solved with this code thanks again for all answers.